# crystal report print plain text in columns

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports, report, plaintext

I have a report in crystal report that shows a list of addresses taken from a db and formatted as follows:

```
`<some codes regarding object to send>
<Name> <Surname>
<Address>
<zip> <City>
<other informations>`
```

I need to print those addresses in 3 or 4 columns (according user choice) in plain text.
With PDF Report there is no problem, but if i set as plain text it shows only one column.
Can you help me?
Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will not change the first answer because maybe it can be useful for someone else.

Here is a very boring new solution, if you do not come up with a better idea. I will write for 3 columns. You will need to adapt for 4 columns (or just create another rpt for 4 columns).

1. Forget the "format with multiple columns" option. Just create a normal detail section.
2. Create the following boring formula. Let's call it as "fieldsFiller":

```
    shared stringvar address1;
    shared stringvar address2;
    shared stringvar address3;
    shared stringvar name1;
    shared stringvar name2;
    shared stringvar name3;
    shared stringvar surname1;
    shared stringvar surname2;
    shared stringvar surname3;
    shared stringvar zip1;
    shared stringvar zip2;
    shared stringvar zip3;
    shared stringvar city1;
    shared stringvar city2;
    shared stringvar city3;
    //TODO do the same for the others fields you need

    if recordnumber mod 3 = 1 then (
        address1 := {YourDataSource.Address};
        name1 := {YourDataSource.Name};
        surname1 := {YourDataSource.Surname};
        zip1 := {YourDataSource.Zip};
        city1 := {YourDataSource.City};
        //TODO do the same for the others fields you need
    )
    else if recordnumber mod 3 = 2 then (
        address2 := {YourDataSource.Address};
        name2 := {YourDataSource.Name};
        surname2 := {YourDataSource.Surname};
        zip2 := {YourDataSource.Zip};
        city2 := {YourDataSource.City};
        //TODO do the same for the others fields you need
    )
    else if recordnumber mod 3 = 0 then (
        address3 := {YourDataSource.Address};
        name3 := {YourDataSource.Name};
        surname3 := {YourDataSource.Surname};
        zip3 := {YourDataSource.Zip};
        city3 := {YourDataSource.City};
        //TODO do the same for the others fields you need
    )
```

3. Put the "fieldsFiller" formula in details section and suppress it.
4. Use section expert on detail section to suppress it according to the following formula:

```
  recordnumber mod 3 > 0
```

5. This will be too boring... Create one formula for each shared variable you declared in "fieldsFiller" formula. For example, create a formula named "address1" with this content:

```
  shared stringvar address1;
  address1;
```

6. Put the formulas in the details section. Put them as fields, side by side.

```
name1 surname1   name2 surname2     name3 surname3
address1         address2           address3
zip1 city1       zip2 city2         zip3 city3
```

7. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

The general idea would be create two details sections. One with 3 columns, the other with 4 columns. And show or hide one of them.

Step by step:

1. Create a parameter with the number of columns. Let's call it {?NumberOfColumns}. I'm assuming, as you said, it can be only 3 or 4.
2. Create two details sections: A and B.
3. Use section expert to suppress detail section A when {?NumberOfColumns} = 4.
4. Use section expert to suppress detail section B when {?NumberOfColumns} = 3.
5. Use section expert on section A. Mark "format with multiple columns". On tab "Layout", set the width to fit only 3 columns in section (~page width/3).
6. Use section expert on section B. Mark "format with multiple columns". On tab "Layout", set the width to fit only 4 columns in section (~page width/4).
7. Put your field in both details sections.
8. Make necessary fine tunes.

Comment: in pdf i have no problems, but when itry to export in plain text, it shows everything in only one column

Comment: Can you change the datasource? If so, you could try to create N fields and put them side by side. You would write a simple algorithm to fill the fields "smartly".

Comment: can you clarify? i have a list of objects with many fields, like Name, Address, etc..
Any address i want to print is made of 3 or 4 lines, i want to have 3 columns o addresses

Comment: When you generate the text file, do the fields "name" and "surname" shows up in the same line? I supposed they do. So, the problem is with the "format with multiple columns" option. So, i'm suggesting a solution without using this option. Instead of it, try to artificially control the "columns" you need by yourself creating more fields and putting them side by side in the detail section (name1, name2, name3, surname1, surname2, surnam3, etc). It is easier to do that if you are generating the datasource programatically. But if you are connecting directly to a database, it can be trickier.